# Spark: JSON Nullable fields handling

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I already raised a question on this but that was for `Array type column`.
Initially thought that the issue was happening only for the JSON array fields but it looks like this happens 
even a for simple scalar field.

Below is the data that I'm loading.

```
val ds = spark.read.textFile("./src/main/resources/json/jsonwithnullfield.txt").as[String]
ds.show(false)

+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|value                                                               |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"title": {"titleId": "111", "titleName": "AAA", "titleDesc": null}}|
|{"title": {"titleId": "222", "titleName": "BBB", "titleDesc": null}}|
|{"title": {"titleId": "333", "titleName": "CCC", "titleDesc": null}}|
|{"title": {"titleId": "444", "titleName": "DDD", "titleDesc": null}}|
|{"title": {"titleId": "555", "titleName": "EEE", "titleDesc": null}}|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Then loaded the Dataset[String] as a JSON 
and I see all the columns in the `schema` including `titleDesc` field.

```
val jsonDF = spark.read.json(ds)
jsonDF.printSchema()
jsonDF.show(false)

root
 |-- title: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- titleDesc: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- titleId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- titleName: string (nullable = true)

+------------+
|title       |
+------------+
|[, 111, AAA]|
|[, 222, BBB]|
|[, 333, CCC]|
|[, 444, DDD]|
|[, 555, EEE]|
+------------+
```

Then I used `to_json function` to convert the `title` value to JSON but the results doesn't seem to be working as expected
as I dont see the `titleDesc` field in the JSON value.

```
jsonDF.select(to_json(struct($"title.*")).as("Title")).show(false)
```

Output:

```
+-----------------------------------+
|Title                              |
+-----------------------------------+
|{"titleId":"111","titleName":"AAA"}|
|{"titleId":"222","titleName":"BBB"}|
|{"titleId":"333","titleName":"CCC"}|
|{"titleId":"444","titleName":"DDD"}|
|{"titleId":"555","titleName":"EEE"}|
+-----------------------------------+
```

I would like to see the `titleDesc` field in the JSON output string.
Is there a workaround in case this cannot be handled through `to_json` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit 1** : As mentioned in comments, in might only work with Spark 3

Depending on your Spark version, you can try to use the `ignoreNullFields` option when applying the `to_json` built-in function.
Would give something like :

```
df.select(to_json($"title", Map("ignoreNullFields" -> "false")).as("myfulljson"))
```

See here, line 81 : https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/json/JSONOptions.scala

**Edit 2** : As suggested, you may use coalesce function to replace null values with empty strings :

```
import spark.implicits._

val jsonDF = spark.read.json(Seq(
  """{"title": {"titleId": "111", "titleName": "AAA", "titleDesc": null}}""",
  """{"title": {"titleId": "222", "titleName": "BBB", "titleDesc": null}}""",
  """{"title": {"titleId": "333", "titleName": "CCC", "titleDesc": null}}""",
  """{"title": {"titleId": "444", "titleName": "DDD", "titleDesc": null}}""",
  """{"title": {"titleId": "555", "titleName": "EEE", "titleDesc": null}}"""
).toDS).select("title.*")

jsonDF.show(false)

+---------+-------+---------+
|titleDesc|titleId|titleName|
+---------+-------+---------+
|null     |111    |AAA      |
|null     |222    |BBB      |
|null     |333    |CCC      |
|null     |444    |DDD      |
|null     |555    |EEE      |
+---------+-------+---------+

jsonDF.select(to_json(struct(jsonDF.columns.map{c => coalesce(col(c), lit("")).as(c)}:_*)).as("title"))
  .show(false)

+--------------------------------------------------+
|title                                             |
+--------------------------------------------------+
|{"titleDesc":"","titleId":"111","titleName":"AAA"}|
|{"titleDesc":"","titleId":"222","titleName":"BBB"}|
|{"titleDesc":"","titleId":"333","titleName":"CCC"}|
|{"titleDesc":"","titleId":"444","titleName":"DDD"}|
|{"titleDesc":"","titleId":"555","titleName":"EEE"}|
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks @@baitmbarek. Im using `spark 2.4.3` doesn't seem to be working. Any idea?

Comment: What about this option : "dropFieldIfAllNull"?

Comment: Tried it. Still no luck!

Comment: ignoreNullFields is a new Spark 3.x feature :( I guess you have to use your own Jackson Mapper with an udf

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
spark.read.json(spark.read.textFile("file.txt")).withColumn("title",struct(col("title.titleId"),col("title.titleName"),lit("").as("titleDesc"))).select(to_json('title)).show(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the workaround that I found for now.

```
ds.withColumn("value",regexp_replace($"value","null", s"""""""")).as[String]
```

Output:

```
jsonDF.show(false)

+--------------------------------------------------+
|Title                                             |
+--------------------------------------------------+
|{"titleDesc":"","titleId":"111","titleName":"AAA"}|
|{"titleDesc":"","titleId":"222","titleName":"BBB"}|
|{"titleDesc":"","titleId":"333","titleName":"CCC"}|
|{"titleDesc":"","titleId":"444","titleName":"DDD"}|
|{"titleDesc":"","titleId":"555","titleName":"EEE"}|
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Glad you found a workaround that suits your need. For same output, you could have used the ``coalesce`` build-in function which deals with ``null`` values for you, replacing them with whatever you want. It's safer and way more performant at scale than regular expressions ;)

Comment: Can you please provide me an example?

Comment: Sure, I'll edit my own reply in few minutes with this example